# WordPress Custom Endpoints in wrong namespace

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a custom endpoint to my WP server. It's supposed to be in the `myplugin/v1` namespace, and the route is `test`. So I would be requesting `/wp-json/myplugin/v1/test`.

I used the following sources to better understand how create such an endpoint:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/

Here is the code that I'm using.

```php
<?php

namespace My_Plugin;

class My_Custom_Routes {
  public static function get_instance() {
    static $instance = null;

    if (is_null($instance)) {
      $instance = new self();
    }

    return $instance;
  }

  private function __construct() {
    $this->register_test_route();
  }

  public function register_test_route() {
    add_action('rest_api_init', function($server) {
      $server->register_route('myplugin/v1', '/test', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => function () {
          return 'foobar';
        }
      ));
    });
  }
}
```

In another file, I make a call to `My_Custom_Routes::get_instance()`, which registers the route.

To check if the route actually registered, I check `/wp-json`. I see `myplugin/v1` is listed underneath the namespaces, and now I check if the routes are there. But the odd thing is that my testing route is listed underneath the empty namespace (I think that's the default namespace, but I'm not entirely sure). So I'd effectively would have to make a call to `/wp-json/test` in order to call my custom endpoint. I included a portion of the response from `/wp-json` below.

```
{
  "routes": {
    "/myplugin/v1": {
      "namespace": "myplugin/v1",
      "methods": [
        "GET"
      ],
      "endpoints": [
        {
          "methods": [
            "GET"
          ],
          "args": {
            "namespace": {
              "required": false,
              "default": "myplugin/v1"
            },
            "context": {
              "required": false,
              "default": "view"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "_links": {
        "self": [
          {
            "href": "https://localhost:3000/wp-json/myplugin/v1"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "/test": {
      "namespace": "",
      "methods": [
        "GET"
      ],
      "endpoints": [
        {
          "methods": [
            "GET"
          ],
          "args": []
        }
      ],
      "_links": {
        "self": [
          {
            "href": "https://localhost:3000/wp-json/test"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Is there something that I overlooked in these documents? I've banged my head on them for the past few hours and can't seem to figure out what's going wrong.